# PHP find all indexes of an array with a certain value without a loop?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I get all indexes of an array that have a certain value? `array_search()` only gives me the first index, but I want all of the indexes. Is there a way to do this

This: `array_search( 'a', array( 'a', 'b', 'a' ) );` would return `0` but what really want in this case would be `0` and `2`.

Comment: there will be a loop, whether you see it or not

Answer (score 4):

`array_search()` will only return the found key, You should use `array_keys` with the second parameter as your needle, it will return both indices `0` and `2`:

```
$key = 'a';
$array = array('a', 'b', 'a');
$found = array_keys($array, $key);
print_r($found); // Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 2 )
```